# Mark Tweets on Facebook with e.g. "from Twitter"

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have setup my Twitter account so that new tweets is automatically posted on my Facebook page. I would like these Facebook posts to be marked with "from Twitter" or similar tag, like it does with Instagram posts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook/twitter integration does that by default.

[image]

If you need something more than this, you probably will have to roll out something on your own